# Python: Combine 2 list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have this 2 list of dictionaries

```
a = [{'Month': 'Sep 2021', 'Like': 6}, {'Month': 'Oct 2021', 'Like': 7}]
b = [{'Month': 'Aug 2021', 'View': 20}, {'Month': 'Oct 2021', 'View': 8}]
```

I want this result

```
c = [{'Month': 'Aug 2021', 'Like': 0, 'View': 20}, 
     {'Month': 'Sep 2021', 'Like': 6, 'View': 0}, 
     {'Month': 'Oct 2021', 'Like': 7, 'View': 8}]
```

I tried this one

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in (a, b):
    for elem in l:
        d[elem['Month']].update(elem)
c = d.values()
```

but the result is this

```
dict_values([{'Month': 'Aug 2021', 'View': 20},
             {'Month': 'Sept 2021', 'Like': 6},
             {'Month': 'Oct 2021', 'Like': 7, 'View': 8}])
```

How can I add 0 if there is no value?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `d = defaultdict(lambda: {'Like': 0, 'View': 0})`?

Comment: it works! Thanks @kaya3

Comment: One of you should provide the answer as actual answer (and accept it), this will be better for future readers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @kaya3 in the comments, I get the result by using

```
 d = defaultdict(lambda: {'Like': 0, 'View': 0})
```